# Opengl undefined behavior

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

I have been experiencing some strange behaviour using Opengl. I am doing something wrong, but I wasn't able to find out what it was.

I have HD Graphics 3000 accelerator and I have Opengl 3.0 installed on Ubuntu 14.04.

The problem is that nothing gets drawn sometimes especially when doing a small translation which should cause it to be visible. When rendering textures I get segmentation errors.

Here are important parts of the code:

Initiating SDL, creating opengl context, etc

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    exit(1);
}

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);



mainwindow = SDL_CreateWindow("", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    512, 512, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);


maincontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mainwindow);

glewInit();;


SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
```

Initiating opengl:

```
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

gluPerspective(45,(double)width/(double)height,1,100.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);  //we enable lighting, to make the 3D object to 3D
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
float col[]= {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0}; //light color is white
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,col);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Rendering:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor ( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0,0,-5);

glColor3f(1,0,0);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,-5);
    glVertex3f(1,-1,-5);
    glVertex3f(0,1,-5);
glEnd();
```

I actually render some loaded models but even this triangle is not shown for some reason. If I render the models, when loading the textures a segmentation fault error happens when using the automatic routine provided by SOIL for loading images to opengl.

Any ideas?
I also check for errors in opengl and also when initiating GLEW, but there aren't any.

Comment: The code you have posted so far is far from complete. Nobody can tell you why it might segfault in the not-posted parts. However, from what is left here, it appears as if you try to texture your triangle with the default texture object, and actually no image, which alone could provoke a all-black result. You could change the background color and check if a black triangle actually appears.

Comment: If I change the background to green, there is no black triangle. I am actually explaining different things which happen. Currently, this is what is run and nothing else. I do not load textures or anything.

Comment: But you enable texturing. Which you shouldn't.

Comment: I copied the code regarding drawing and it seems that my models are rendered correctly. Maybe there is some problem with the Opegl context or something like that and I am doing something terribly bad. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I worked with Opengl (call lightning, set view, etc) without initiating SDL and creating a context. Strangely, Opengl didn't call any errors.